# my jar file doesn't load images that i added via scene builder. (JAVAFX)

Tags: java, javafx, jar, fxml, scenebuilder

so the problem is as follows:

I created an FXML file and edited it with JAVA SCENE BUILDER.

on the scene builder i added an image view and set the path to the file

[scene builder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGqyn.jpg)

the code in the fxml file is:

```
<ImageView fitHeight="285.0" fitWidth="301.0" layoutX="94.0" layoutY="94.0" opacity="0.26" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="@../../src/view/images/mainpic.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
```

now i have a main class that loads that FXML file.
and the image is in the src file.

pic related:

[tree of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtynN.jpg)

when i run the main from eclipse the picture is loaded correctly.
but when i create a jar file the image is not loaded.

question is:
how do i get the jar file to get the images specified in the fxml file?

also code of main:

```
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/view/mainMenuView.fxml");
 AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load( url );
 StackPane p = new StackPane();
 p.getChildren().add(pane);
 StackPane.setAlignment(pane,Pos.CENTER);
 Scene scene = new Scene( p);
 // setting the stage
 primaryStage.setScene( scene );
 primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Try `@images/mainpic.png` (The fxml seems to be inside the `view` package.) In a jar file there simply is no directory above the root, which would in this case be the directory containing `view`.

Comment: ok i figured it out.

Comment: wow we commented the same time. that's exactly what i did fabian thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for fabian to answer the question right.
realizing the same thing as fabian the answer is that

```
@images/mainpic.png
```

is the right path to the picture.